# Conditional Probability

Tags: probability, random-variables

could you help with this:

Let $x_{1},x_{2}$ ~ Geo(p)

i'd like to know:

i  got:

P($x_{1} = k$ | $x_{1} + x_{2}$) = $\frac{P(x_{1} =k;x_{2} = n-k)}{P(x_{1}+x_{2} = n)}$ =  $\frac{P(x_{1}=k) \times P(x_{2} = n-k)}{P(x_{1}+x_{2} = n)}$ = $\frac{(1-p)^kp(1-p)^{n-k}p}{\sum_{k=0}^{n} (1-p)^kp(1-p)^{n-k}p}$ = 1

but accoring my equations that is to be equals 1. it is correct (i don't think so)? how to solve it ?

Thanks Guys.

Comment: You have a ratio with a sum of multiple terms on the bottom, and just _one_ of those terms on top. Why _ever_ would you think that is equal to $1$? You wouldn't write $3/(2+3+4+5)=1,$ would you?

Comment: It helps to specify *which* Geometric Distribution you are using.  It looks like "count of failures before first success" or $x_1\in\{0,1,\ldots\}$.

Comment: David, following the equation and if we simplify we get something like a / a (a!=0).
I agree with you , Graham, but how to solve this conditional probability ? any tip ?

Comment: On the contrary, you do not get anything at all like $a/a.$. If you had shown the intermediate steps of your simplification in your question, it would have been simple to point out the error. But the correct calculation has been given in an answer, so perhaps you can see it yourself.

Comment: Oh... Yes, on answear below i saw my error, and you are correct, it is not a a/a. Thanks Guys

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is cancelation, but you have a series in the denominator.
$$ f_{x_1\mid x_1+x_2}(k\mid n)~{=~\dfrac{(1-p)^k p\cdot (1-p)^{n-k}p}{\sum_{j=0}^n [(1-p)^j p\cdot (1-p)^{n-j}p]}\\=~\dfrac{(1-p)^{n}p^2}{\sum_{j=0}^n [(1-p)^n p^2]}\\=~\dfrac{1}{\sum_{j=0}^n 1} \\=~\dfrac 1{n+1}}$$

Also note that the support for this function is: $\{(k,n)\in\Bbb Z^2: 0\leq k\leq n\}$

Now, can you identify the distribution family?

Comment: PS: Some errors of confusion can be avoided by *not reusing* the same variable in the numerator for the series' iterator in the denominator.

Comment: Thanks so much man, but i didnt see the distribution family, is it a regular/known distribution ?

Comment: Very much so,@RobertMota  What well-known distribution do you know has the form $~p_{\small Y}(y) = \dfrac{1}{n+1}~\big[y\in\{0,\ldots, n\}\big]~$?

Comment: this seems like a uniforme distribution is not it ?

Comment: @RobertMota The conditional distribution of $x_1$ given $x_1+x_2$ is a *Uniform Discrete Distribution*, to be exact.